# ADIS16507-1 on Raspberry Pi 4, spi_bcm2835: disagrees about version of symbol

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi, raspberry-pi4, insmod, iio

I want to use my ADIS16507-1 sensor on my Raspberry Pi 4 but I can't see my sensor.

I explain you step by step. To use my sensor I have to compile [the Analog Devices kernel](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-build/generic/raspberrypi) by modifying the configuration file as indicated by the manufacturer so that it is adapted to my sensor [ADIS16475 IIO](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-drivers/iio-inertial-measurement-units/adis16475).

Once this step is done I will put my new kernel on a SD card where I put the version of Raspberry Pi OS Lite : *2021-10-30-raspios-bullseye-armhf-lite.img*

Once my Raspberry pi 4 is running I should normally see my sensor

```
$ ls /sys/bus/iio/devices/
iio:device0
```

But I don't have *iio:device0*.

I think that the problem comes from my spi_bcm2835 module because when my raspberry starts I have in the logs :

```
$ dmesg
spi_bcm2835: disagrees about version of symbol dev_driver_string
spi_bcm2835: Unknown symbol dev_driver_string (err -22)
spi_bcm2835: disagrees about version of symbol _dev_info
spi_bcm2835: Unknown symbol _dev_info (err -22)
spi_bcm2835: disagrees about version of symbol _dev_err
spi_bcm2835: Unknown symbol _dev_err (err -22)
spi_bcm2835: disagrees about version of symbol __devm_spi_alloc_controller
spi_bcm2835: Unknown symbol __devm_spi_alloc_controller (err -22)
spi_bcm2835: disagrees about version of symbol spi_unregister_controller
spi_bcm2835: Unknown symbol spi_unregister_controller (err -22)
spi_bcm2835: disagrees about version of symbol spi_split_transfers_maxsize
spi_bcm2835: Unknown symbol spi_split_transfers_maxsize (err -22)
spi_bcm2835: disagrees about version of symbol _dev_warn
spi_bcm2835: Unknown symbol _dev_warn (err -22)
spi_bcm2835: disagrees about version of symbol dev_err_probe
spi_bcm2835: Unknown symbol dev_err_probe (err -22)
spi_bcm2835: disagrees about version of symbol spi_register_controller
spi_bcm2835: Unknown symbol spi_register_controller (err -22)
```

I can't load this module with *modprobe* or *insmod*.
Another problem, the list of module errors like the one above in my *dmesg* is still very long.

```
rfkill: disagrees about version of symbol put_device
rfkill: Unknown symbol put_device (err -22)
uio: disagrees about version of symbol kobject_uevent
uio: Unknown symbol kobject_uevent (err -22)
llc: disagrees about version of symbol consume_skb
llc: Unknown symbol consume_skb (err -22)
...
```

And I can't load any modules.

```
sudo modprobe spi-bcm2835
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'spi_bcm2835': Invalid argument
```

The error could be from my kernel version but I have a feeling it's good.

```
uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.63-v7l+ #2 SMP Mon Jun 27 01:50:44 PDT 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

My kernel is version 5.10.63-v7l+ just like [Analog Devices kernel](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-build/generic/raspberrypi).

I'm running out of ideas to find my problem. Ask me if I have not provided enough detail.
Thanks a lot in advance,

---

I found a solution. I don't go through the Analog Device kernel anymore.

I put on my SD card the last version of [Raspberry Pi lite OS](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/#raspberry-pi-os-32-bit). Then I launch my Raspberry Pi and I [update](https://angristan.fr/mettre-a-jour-raspberry-pi-sous-raspbian/) to get the same kernel version as the [Raspberry Pi Github](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux).

To check on my Raspberry Pi :

```
uname -r
5.15.50-v7l+
```

To check on Github I look in linux/Makefile

```
VERSION = 5
PATCHLEVEL = 15
SUBLEVEL = 50
```

Once I have the same version, I do exactly the same steps as the Raspberry Pi tuto [the Raspberry Pi tuto](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html) and I add in my .config my driver.

```
CONFIG_SPI_MASTER=y
CONFIG_IIO=y
CONFIG_ADIS16475=m
CONFIG_IIO_KFIFO_BUF=y
CONFIG_SPI_BCM2835=y
```

Thanks to that I added my ADIS16475 driver on my kernel and I just have to load it by doing

```
sudo modprobe adis16475
```

however in my case I still have this error in the ***dmesg*** when I modporbe

```
SPI driver adis16475 has no spi_device_id for adi,adis16470
SPI driver adis16475 has no spi_device_id for adi,adis16475-1
SPI driver adis16475 has no spi_device_id for adi,adis16475-2
SPI driver adis16475 has no spi_device_id for adi,adis16475-3
SPI driver adis16475 has no spi_device_id for adi,adis16477-1
SPI driver adis16475 has no spi_device_id for adi,adis16477-2
SPI driver adis16475 has no spi_device_id for adi,adis16477-3
SPI driver adis16475 has no spi_device_id for adi,adis16465-1
SPI driver adis16475 has no spi_device_id for adi,adis16465-2
SPI driver adis16475 has no spi_device_id for adi,adis16465-3
SPI driver adis16475 has no spi_device_id for adi,adis16467-1
SPI driver adis16475 has no spi_device_id for adi,adis16467-2
SPI driver adis16475 has no spi_device_id for adi,adis16467-3
SPI driver adis16475 has no spi_device_id for adi,adis16500
SPI driver adis16475 has no spi_device_id for adi,adis16505-1
SPI driver adis16475 has no spi_device_id for adi,adis16505-2
SPI driver adis16475 has no spi_device_id for adi,adis16505-3
SPI driver adis16475 has no spi_device_id for adi,adis16507-1
SPI driver adis16475 has no spi_device_id for adi,adis16507-2
SPI driver adis16475 has no spi_device_id for adi,adis16507-3
```

I also asked the question on the [ADI Engineer zone](https://ez.analog.com/mems/f/q-a/560360/spi-driver-adis16475-has-no-spi_device_id-for-adi-adis16470)

Comment: Have you built your kernel with `CONFIG_ADIS16475=m`? Have you enabled it in Device Tree?

Comment: Note, you shouldn't see _/dev/spi*_ if you are using in-kernel driver.

Comment: I have been searching for a while and my situation has progressed. I am updating my post

Comment: You are building and trying to run on a different kernel versions. Fix that first, and else will be much easier.

Comment: The version of the kernel I put on my SD card (2021-10-30-raspios-bullseye-armhf-lite.img) is according to a uname -r : 5.10.63-v7l+ and the version of the kernel of analog devices is : 5.10.63-v7l+ according to /linux/lib/modules/ 5.10.63-v7l+/ I have the impression that they are the same one not?

Comment: My modules are compiled for the right kernel $modinfo spi-bcm2835 : vermagic: 5.10.63-v7l+, the "Unknown symbol xxx (err -22)" exist all in /proc/kallsyms . I don't understand why modprobe or insmod can't make the link

Comment: I downloaded "sudo apt install raspberrypi-kernel-headers" and "make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules" in my /lib/modules/5.10.63-v7l+/build to see if it changed anything but it did nothing

Comment: however, the name in "Unknown symbol xxx (err -22)" does not exist in /lib/modules/5.4.83-v7l+/build/Module.symvers

Comment: the answer is here : https://ez.analog.com/mems/f/q-a/560360/spi-driver-adis16475-has-no-spi_device_id-for-adi-adis16470